# How you say to take notes/information in this context?

Tags: vocabulary, phrasal-verbs

The idea is that *take notes* means to store info about something, so is this context correct?

> I placed an order, but they didn't note well my info.

When you are taking somebody's info, how do you say it? You write it down? You note it? You take notes?

Sorry, I'm Spanish and in Spain you say "apuntar". Ellos apuntaron mal mis datos. But I don't know how to say it in English.

How could you say that in the next phrase?

> I placed an order last friday and it has not arrived yet. They may not have noted it well

Comment: I'd use "properly" instead of "well", maybe something like "they didn't take down my order properly", or "take down my details properly". Although "info" isn't wrong.

Comment: "They didn't record my information properly." "They may not have recorded it correctly."

Comment: In American English, I wouldn't likely use the word "note" at all. I would probably say something more like, "Maybe they got my address wrong" or "They may have  made a mistake entering my info in the computer".

Comment: thanks guys, precious information, it helped a lot, thanks :)